# Calling a bound script from a different container

Tags: google-apps-script

Essentially I want to use a bound script in a Google Form to call a function in a Google Sheet that will go and edit yet another sheet.  Ideally I could eliminate those steps if the onEdit trigger in the data sheet would get called when a new form submission happens, but that isn't working so now we're here.  I really just need the syntax to know how to trigger a bound function in the Sheet's script by running the onFormSubmission trigger that is bound to a Google Form.

I haven't really tried much, I think all I need is to be told that it is impossible, OR HOPEFULLY just to see what the proper syntax is.  I'm new to Google Apps Script, I think I'm like 2 hours in or so.

```
function onFormSubmit() {
    //call the populateJournal() function that is bound to the Sheet
}
```

After I get this done I'm gonna need to have the populateJournal() function edit a sheet that is another container entirely, and I'm guessing that syntax is gonna look marginally similar in terms of referencing an external container.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, my apologies for my ineptitude.

Comment: I think you can do this with the new app script API. But I’ve never used it myself I just read about it.

Comment: Is the form linked to the sheet? If so, you can just use `onFormSubmit()` for your sheet instead.

Comment: You can link your Google Form and Sheets by following the steps shown under 'Collect form responses' at https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2917686?hl=en. With the form and Sheet linked, you can seamlessly run the Sheet scripts from the form by adding the `onFormSubmit()`. Instead of calling `onClick()`, is it feasible to put the code you want to run `onFormSubmit()` in a third function, and then call it from both `onClick()` and `onFormSubmit()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to send the form responses to the spreadsheet by using the built-in feature for that, instead of using the on form submit event of the bounded to form script uses the on form submit event of the bounded to spreadsheet script.